# Python mocking and patching https client for unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing unit tests and I need to mock a library to test my database result, but I am not sure of what the mock syntax would be for my test. Sample pseudo code:

in **utils.py**

```
import hvac

def setup_client():
    client = hvac.Client(url="vault.internal", verify=False)
    # More customized client logic here
    return client
```

in my function code **api.py**:

```
from utils import setup_client

def send_and_save(data: str):
    client = setup_client()
    result = client.send("test_data")
    # Pseudo code to save to the database 
    database.save(data)
```

I want to be able to write a test that tests that `send_and_save` method saved `data` into the database in **api.py** without needing to call `setup_client()` at all.

What I've attempted in **test_api.py**

```
@patch("utils.setup_client", autospec=True)
def test_data_processed():
    // Code to trigger send_and_save("test_data") here. Note that I cannot test 
    // send_and_save("data") 
    // by calling it directly since this is part of a legacy
    // integration test than a unit test just for send_and_save

    setup_client.return_value = None
    assert database.get("key") == "test_data"
```

I am still getting an error from python trying to setup the client as if it's running the real client. How do I setup mock and patch to bypass this?

Comment: can you elaborate on the error? which error do you get?

Comment: it seems that you are returning None from the setup_client function which will raise an error in the     result = client.send("test_data") line.

Comment: ```               raise SSLError(e, request=request)
               requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8200): Max retries exceeded with url:```, which happens during the setup_client() function, it looks like the real setup_client() is still being called.

Answer (score 0):

Your patch should point to where the function is being called, not where the function exists.

[patch decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

```
@patch("api.setup_client", autospec=True)
def test_data_processed():
    mocked_client = MagicMock()
    mocked_client.send.return_value = 'Fake result'
    setup_client.return_value = mocked_client
    assert database.get("key") == "test_data"
```